# How to use javascript to validate Telerik RadDatePicker for invalid dates entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, telerik, telerik-datepicker

I'm using two `RadDatePicker` controls showing `Date From` and `Date To` and need to make sure that before submitting the form, at least one of the date is provided.

I have a `JavaScript` code checking to make sure that the user provides at least one date value:

```
function validateDates(sender, eventArgs) {

    var datePicker1 = $find("<%=RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
    var datePicker2 = $find("<%=RadDatePicker2.ClientID %>");


    if (datePicker1.get_selectedDate() == null && datePicker2.get_selectedDate() == null) 
    {
        alert("At least one date should be selected");
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }

       //alert(datePicker1.lastSetTextBoxValue.value);
       //return false;
}
```

That part works.

However, a user can also type a string in which case, it will also fails with the same message, because `get_selecteddate()` method also returns null.

But, what I want is to actually check if the value entered is of a date format and display the corresponding message to the user.

So, in my case, I would need to use a validation for the correct date format as well.

I noticed that when `Telerik DatePicker` is rendered, it builds the following `html` sections:

```
<input id="ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_RadDatePicker1_dateInput" name="ctl00$Contentplaceholder2$RadDatePicker1$dateInput" class="riTextBox riError" type="text" style="">

<input id="ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_RadDatePicker1_dateInput_ClientState" name="ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_RadDatePicker1_dateInput_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;minDateStr&quot;:&quot;1980-01-01-00-00-00&quot;,&quot;maxDateStr&quot;:&quot;2099-12-31-00-00-00&quot;,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;hhh&quot;}">
```

From that `html` I see that when a string is entered into a `DatePicker`, its `input` element gets assigned a `css` class called `riError` and its `lastSetTextBoxValue` has a string I entered.

So, I can assume, I can use those two properties to improve my validation logic.

How can I do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you attach some codepen/etc? :)

Comment: What do you mean? You need to see asp code for the controls?

Comment: even tho you use server side to build it, the question is a pure client side issue. so, try to get it as a single html+js code, and use a codepen or similar service. why? because it's easier for us to "play with" and understand. also - try to give example values for the handling cases.

Some of us has no experience with the specific tech (like me), but knows enough to solve it, it will make it easier.. and a nice gesture :)